# How to use google cloud trace SDK for java via gradle

Tags: java, gradle, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-trace

How to use the following in gradle?

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-trace-java

I don't see it in maven repository

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/cloud-trace-java

Comment: That's not Maven Central... This is http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.cloud.trace%7Csdk%7C0.3.2%7C

Comment: Thanks I tried     testCompile 'com.google.cloud.trace:sdk:0.3.2' still unable to  import com.google.cloud.trace.Trace;

Comment: Why are you trying to use `testCompile`?

Comment: my code is actually a Junit @Test , inside test package . It did not work with compile also.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include both your Gradle files?